# CSS vs SVG for layout

Tags: html, css, layout, svg

I'm developing a web application that has a certain layout.
I'm mainly using CSS for styling the buttons and using divs and styling them for other layout items.
The problem is that sometimes I need a layout item to be non-rectangular.
Also- designing SVG is easeer and sometimes may produce better results.
My question is: should I use CSS always for the layout, and for instance- combine divs to achieve the non-rectangular effect- or should I use SVG for some of the layout items?
Also- what about the buttons- CSS or SVG?
Thanks!

Comment: there is no CSS vs SVG, they are not in the same plan: CSS styles HTML as well as SVG. you probably meant HTML or SVG

Comment: BiAiB: Read the question again. It makes sense. They are asking whether to use SVG to render some page elements where the desired styling cannot be achieved with CSS.

Comment: You say that non-rectangular items are a problem. Could you elaborate? Are they a problem specifically concerning their layout? Why?
Have you considered designing a visually appealing button with svg and then placing it on the page using css?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bear in mind that SVG isn't supported in older browsers. In particular, in IE8 and earlier. Using SVG will therefore limit your audience.

It is possible to rig older versions of IE to support SVG - there are a number of Javascript libraries which can convert SVG into VML, which was Microsoft's proprietary alternative to SVG. However, this does mean you're running Javascript code unnecessarily; you could cause performance issues in IE, or worse, it could load slow enough that the layout redraws after its loaded.

Therefore, for cross-browser compatiblity reasons, I would suggest not using SVG for your basic page layout.

Where I would use SVG is for graphs and charts, etc. For these, I would use the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) javascript library, which makes drawing SVG very easy, and also renders it as VML in IE, without you having to do any explicit conversion.

For creating non-square elements in CSS, there is a hack which uses the CSS borders to draw triangles and other shapes. This works in all browsers (with some minor caveats in IE6), so is great for creating spot-effects like marker arrows and speech bubbles.

See http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/creating-triangles-in-css/ for more info on this.

Great for spot effects, but should stress that I wouldn't recommend it for complex shapes; I have seen some people drawing entire pictures using it -- see http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/fivestar and other hacks on the same site -- but as I say, I wouldn't suggest actually doing this, except just to demo a hack like this guy.

Hope that helps.

[EDIT]
Per the OP's comments, he only wants to add a rectangular protruding part to a larger rectangular `<div>`, so in fact the shape he's trying to create isn't all that complex after all; in fact, it sounds a lot like a tab. Given this, the best recommendation by far is to forget about drawing it with SVG, and simply create two divs: one for the main content and one for the tab. If necessary, a third div can be created to wrap the other two. This may be helpful for referencing the two others together via CSS or Javascript.

Comment: Thanks. Good points. But like you say- creating non-square elements in CSS is a "hack". The border isn't intended for that. I want a normal way to do such things. That's why I thought SVG is good.

Comment: @amitairos - it's a choice: a small hack but good browser compatibility or SVG but exclude IE users. I know which way I'd go. Maybe switch to SVG for this sort of thing in five years time when the last IE8 users finally get forced to upgrade.

Comment: Ok. It still seems complex and not "clean". What about embeding svg or using an image of svg?

Comment: @amitairos - see my response to your comment in the other answer. You're overcomplicating things in your search for a "clean" answer; the cleanest and simplest way to do what you want is simply to have a second `<div>` for the protruding bit.

Comment: I see. It's just that when I think of divs- I don't think of them as a shape and that they can be grouped to one larger shape. I think of divs as an element...

Comment: @amitairos - so use a different element then... maybe a `<button>` or a `<ul><li>` combination (commonly used for tabs) or.... there's still no need to break out of HTML for what you're doing.

Comment: IE8 not supporting is getting old, Not supporting IE8 isn't as big as it sounds. There is somewhere between 2% to 3% usage around the world and by actively supporting old IE versions we keep it alive. I always recommend using SVG because its a powerful tool and it should be used not overlooked. Don't use SVG for layout, its not its purpose. Creating shapes is its main purpose, I would also say that some buttons can be created with SVG, but not an entire div.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to advise you not using SVG for the layout, it's not really its purpose. It's best suited for diagrams, pictograms, charts or maps etc.

using SVG will have disavantages:
-First, support: IE<9 doesnt support SVG, or you'd need an external plugin.
-Integration: it's easy to have SVG inside HTML, but emmbeding HTML in SVG is quite unpractical. 
-flow in layout: you can draw shapes easily, but placing blocks/text has to be done manually. in html two consecutive blocks will be displayed one below the second. In SVG you have to place them absolutely, ensure text inside them isn't too long cause their size won't adjust automatically.

I'm almost sure it would be easier to layout with HTML+CSS. And now with CSS3 you can rotate blocks, round borders, cast shadow. I would like to know which particular layout cause you problems.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having a problem making an element non-rectangular- that has a rectangle protruding from the side of a square. I know I can use two divs, but that isn't "clean".

Comment: @amitairos - the extra `<div>` for the protruding bit is perfectly "clean". It's a very common technique. You don't even need to use the triangle hack I talked about in my answer; it's just a second div. If you want it to be "clean" (ie a single element representing the whole thing including the protruding bit) then use a wrapper div around them both.

Comment: Yes, with CSS3 transforms you can e.g rotate html elements. But IE<9 doesn't support that. You'd need hacks or workarounds for that too. Also you don't in all cases need a plugin for IE to render "svg", if you use an abstraction layer such as Raphaël that translates the drawing commands to VML.

Answer (score 2):

We are in 2017 now, I belive that all major browsers support SVG.
So I would say SVG is a good option. You will probably need to use JavaScript to adjust elements on the screen and make them responsive, because SVG does not provide things such as flexbox, tables, float, etc. The advantage with that is that you will have more flexibility and will not have to deal with the limitations and side effects of CSS.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "side effects" of CSS? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Crashalot Some examples from memory: overflow:hidden clips overflow but also causes floating children to behave differently. position:relative enables offset positioning but also sets the element as reference for child absolute positioning. Floating also disables collapsing margins. So many times I was working with CSS, and wanted to do one thing and then one such "side effect" broke my design somewhere else, then I spent a long time trying to separate the effect that I wanted from the undesired side effect, only to find out that it is impossible and I have to re-think the whole design.